# Service Accounts in SQL Server

Tags: service-accounts

I wanted to get a list of all the service accounts available in Microsoft SQL Server, I was able to see through Configuration Manager, and also by running this query in SSMS
"select
servicename,
status_desc,
last_startup_time,
service_account,
filename,
is_clustered
from sys.dm_server_services""
But the issue i'm having is that the service accounts are listed quite alright but I also needed the following information, the service account, who is it assigned to, if it is not in use, when last it was used